# Android Studio giving error while compiling project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

```
ParseError at [row,col]:[82,9]
Message: Attribute name "vis" associated with an element type "View" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

Any help what could be the issue as I am unable to find out what is the issue in which file.

Comment: You need to publish the code that is causing this error! I suspect you have a bad xml in your layouts, but there really is no way to tell.

Comment: I cannot post whole code here, this error doesnt give any detail where this error could be, how can I know which xml has issue?

Comment: You must have got this error , due to your recent change in the xml . Recollect where you did that and check particular xml

Comment: Looks like you've hit ENTER after android:vis  ...  ibility somwhere in XML file

Comment: @MobileDeveloperiOSAndroid you should look at the verbose compiler output. See which file was processed. Alternatively, search your layout xml files for the word `vis`. As MarkWalczak pointed out, looks like you have a broken attribute name somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`vis` attribute is not provided by `android` namespace `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` . Unfortunately somehow this `vis` keyword inserted in your resource file (xml) inside `View` element based on error message (not others views such TextView/Button etc) . This `vis` expecting `=` to assign its value . Unfortunately I guess that `vis` dont have `=` .

You may have `vis"somevalue"` or `vis` in `View` . Suppose -

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    vis"somevalue"
    android:text="Test" />
```

This condition will generate such error . So you may search `vis"` or `vis` keyword  by `Find in Files` through right click on `res` directory to remove the unwanted line of code.